# Iptables rules to allow appVM to pass through proxyVM configured to only go through a VPN in QubesOS

Tags: iptables, samba, vpn, cifs, qubes

I am trying to allow my appVM to communicate with my samba server on my local network. The problem is that I am forcing this appVM to go through a proxyVM which doesn't allow traffic to pass through unless its going via the VPN (openvpn).

So I am trying to add iptables rules to allow this, but I can't seem to get it to work, and am wondering what I am missing. The following rule is the one I add to the proxyVPN (which should be the only VM I have to edit, right?)

```
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -d <samba-server-ip> -p tcp -m multiport --dports 137:139,445 -j ACCEPT
```

After attempting to connect to the server I can see that the target rule gets hit a couple of times (6 to be exact), but I am still getting

```
"mount error(115): Operation in progress"
```

error message from the appVM when trying to mount a cifs-share. I also cannot see any DROP rules being hit, which leads me to believe that maybe I will have to edit the iptables rules in the firewallVM or the netVM or even the appVM, but I can't think of why that should be.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I needed to add a route to my samba server in the routing table, otherwise it would try to route everything through the VPN interface.

```
ip route add <samba-ip>/32 via <sys-firewall-ip>
```

This solved everything.